# How to update a SwiftUI navigationlink view from an observableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Consider this MRE

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = VM()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(vm.list, id: \.self) { int in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(vm: vm, x: int)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(int)")
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    vm.changeFirstElement()
                } label: {
                    Text("change")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM
    let x: Int
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(x)")
            Button {
                vm.changeFor(index:x) //how to make this work?
            } label: {
                Text("change")
            }
        }
    }
}

class VM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    func changeFirstElement() {
        list[0] = 5
    }
}
```

You can see that in the main view, change() works, the view redraws

But inside the detail view, even though it has observed object it doesn't. How can I make it so that changes in the data model is reflected even inside the Detail View?

Comment: You're keying the `ForEach` by `self`. That's usually a dangerous recipe. If you want the view to update, you should use truly unique IDs and then have a sub property of the model that has the actual value.

Comment: @jnpdx can you provide a working example?

Comment: I can, but I'd like to be more sure it matches your requirements first. What I'm envisioning is something where your list is an array of `Model` where each `Model` has an `id` and a `value`. On the button press, the `value` will update. Will that work for you?

Comment: @jnpdx yes that will work but it should update the corresponding element. For example if the detail view is currently showing elements 3 of a list, a button in the detail view should update the value of element 3 and the detail view should redraw to reflect that. Does that makes sense?

Comment: `StateObject` isn't designed for VMs you need to learn the View struct features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI, there are many cases (like `ForEach` and `List`) where it's useful to have `Identifiable` data. In fact, if you're using `id: self`, it's *usually* a sign of something going wrong.

By using an `Identifiable` model, everything "just works":

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = VM()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(vm.list) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(vm: vm, item: item)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(item.value)")
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    vm.change()
                } label: {
                    Text("change")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM
    let item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(item.value)")
            Button {
                vm.change()
            } label: {
                Text("change")
            }
        }
    }
}

class VM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [Item] = [.init(value: 1), .init(value: 2), .init(value: 3)]
    func change() {
        list[0].value = 5
    }
}
```

Note that it's also debatable whether you would need the `VM` at all here -- you could just use a `Binding` from the `ForEach`. Here's a version using a `Binding` on the `ForEach`:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = VM()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach($vm.list) { $item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(item: $item)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(item.value)")
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    vm.list[0].value = 5
                } label: {
                    Text("change")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(item.value)")
            Button {
                item.value = 5
            } label: {
                Text("change")
            }
        }
    }
}

class VM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [Item] = [.init(value: 1), .init(value: 2), .init(value: 3)]
}
```

And, if for some reason you truly need to use indices, you can do this:

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var value: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = VM()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(Array(vm.list.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (index, item) in
                    NavigationLink {
                        DetailView(vm: vm, item: item, index: index)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(item.value)")
                    }
                }
                Button {
                    vm.changeFirstElement()
                } label: {
                    Text("change")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: VM
    let item: Item
    let index: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(item.value)")
            Button {
                vm.changeAtIndex(index)
            } label: {
                Text("change")
            }
        }
    }
}

class VM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var list: [Item] = [.init(value: 1), .init(value: 2), .init(value: 3)]
    func changeFirstElement() {
        list[0].value = 5
    }
    
    func changeAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
        list[index].value = 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi your answer works perfectly, however I've edited the question to be a bit more clear. DetailView is suppose to show one particular element of a list. DetailView also has a need to update the value of the corresponding element in the list, not just always hard coded to be the first element. How can this be done?

Comment: Does the `change` function have to happen in the `VM`? Does it have to be based on `index`? If not, have you tried a `Binding` on `ForEach` like I suggest in the post? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-a-list-or-a-foreach-from-a-binding

Comment: I've updated the answer with a `ForEach` `Binding` and an example that uses indices. I would not use the indices version unless you truly need to -- always prefer relying on IDs.

Comment: Thanks the answer is perfect. I've accepted it but can you explain how swiftui redraws? In the second example, I suppose the binding keyword tells swiftui that there is a dependency and it redraws when list is modified? But even then how does the first example work? Is that the magic of @ObservedObject? What if @ObservedObject is removed and list is modified externally, will it still redraw?

Comment: Talking about how SwiftUI decides to redraw and re-rerender is a pretty big topic for the comments section. I'd suggest watching "Demystify SwiftUI" from WWDC, which will clear a lot of this up and goes into quite a bit of depth. Regarding removing `@ObservedObject`, if you mean from `DetailView`, yes, it will still redraw, because the data is coming from the parent `View`, not the `VM`. You can try that yourself by removing the property wrapper.